# Python 3 venv interpreter not available in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am following this [Django App Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/)  and I ran into this error from models.py

Error: `Unable to import 'django.db'`

models.py code below

```
from django.db import models
```

I am new to python and django so I followed the following steps in creating the app for python 3.

STEPS:

1. Followed this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2q_b4ugPWk) to change the PATH of Python 3.
2. In the cmd I ran the following:

```
>python --version                              [ RESULT: Python 3.8.2 ]
>python -m venv polling-website
>Scripts/activate                              [Successfully activated]
>py -m pip install Django                      [Django version 3.0.6]
>django-admin startproject mysite
>python manage.py migrate
>python manage.py startapp polls
>py manage.py runserver
```

I was able to activate the virtual environment and the django server ran successfully.

I noticed that the virtual environment I made for the project cannot be identified by the Command Palette when I use **Python: Select Interpreter** command.

[image: Image of command palette with no venv option]

How will I be able to make the venv interpreter appear?

What mistake was made in installing the Django App?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your environment is not in [one of the standard places VS Code looks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_where-the-extension-looks-for-environments) for them.

You could try the steps at [manually specifying an environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter) (paraphrased):

> 1. First, select File/Code > Preferences > Settings to open your Settings, select Workspace.
> 2. Create or modify an entry for python.pythonPath with the full path to the Python executable:
>
>    - Windows: "python.pythonPath": "c:/dev/ala/venv/Scripts/python.exe",
>    - macOS/Linux: "python.pythonPath": "/home/abc/dev/ala/venv/bin/python",

Comment: It turns out that a folder for venv was not created when i created a virtual environment. I searched "virtualenvs" in my windows explorer and the folder was empty. What could be wrong with my installation?

Comment: `python -m venv polling-website` creates a virtualenv named `polling-website` in your current working directory.

Comment: Does this mean I shouldn't install my venv in my desktop since it is not where vscode looks for its interpreters?

Comment: If you like to do that, you can add your desktop to the `python.venvPath` setting (you _did_ read the first link thoroughly, right?), and VS Code would pick that up. But in general, no, I wouldn't keep envs on the desktop.

Comment: I was finally able to get the documentation you sent thank you! I was copying the wrong path for the virtual environment created which was located within my project folder. 

What is the best practice for handling virtual environments? Rather where is the best place to store them?

Comment: I keep them in an `envs` folder in my user directory; some people swear by having a `venv` folder (that's git-ignored) in the project directory.